# Can I secure a compute engine instance to ONLY allow cloud run AND my personal home ip (for testing)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-cloud-run

We would like to lockdown some compute engine VMS so that the only ones that can access it are

- cloud run instances (ideally just ours)
- a few home ip addresss
- a few NAT ips of the office

Is this possible?

Comment: Both answers below are good. However, define what you mean by NAT IPs? Google Cloud will not see your internal NAT'd IP addresses. You can create firewall rules for your `public` IP address but not for selective addresses inside your home/office network. Cloud Run is a shared resource so you cannot use public IP based rules. Provide more details on what you are trying to protect. The best solution will use `identity` based authorization and not IP based identification.

Answer (score 1):

For limiting the access to your compute engines from few IP (your personal IP or nat IPs from your office), you can use firewall rules for this.

For allowing only Cloud Run to access to your compute engines, I recommend you to do this

- [Create a dedicated VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#creating_networks) for your compute engines
- Deploy your compute engines in this new VPC
- Create a [serverless VPC connector to access to the new VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access)
- [Deploy Cloud Run services with this serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)
- Access to your compute engines from Cloud Run services **by only the private IP**.

*Normally, if you set correctly your previous firewall rules, if you try to reach your compute engines from Cloud Run by the public IP, you should have an access denied.*

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run does not support IP-based firewalling.

However, you can always implement it yourself in your application by looking at the `X-Forwarded-For` header which will contain the origin IP address of the client.

If you want to limit access to other Cloud Run applications, do not deploy your app with the "allow authenticated" box checked. This way your app will require identity-token authentication which is described at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service. To do that, you need to deploy other Cloud Run services you have with a custom service account, then you need to set permissions for that service account to be able to access the service you are restricting.

**Edit:** It seems I misunderstood the question as "how to restrict access to Cloud Run by IPs such as a few IP addresses or GCE instances". Guillaume's answer is accurate.